# MassTransit RabbitMQ not working on .NET Framework 4.8

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, masstransit, .net-4.8

Recently I tried to add MassTransit consumer for RabbitMQ on a legacy project that using .NET Framework 4.8. When I push message to the queue, nothing happened but the message end up in the skipped queue with reason of DeadLetter. When I check the Output, I saw that error

`Assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=7.0.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxx' is marked with the AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute, and uses the level 2 security transparency model.  Level 2 transparency causes all methods in AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers assemblies to become security transparent by default, which may be the cause of this exception. 'xxx' (CLR v4.0.xxxxx: Host): Loaded 'MassTransit.SerializationGreenPipes.DynamicInternalxxx'.  'xxx' (CLR v4.0.xxxxx: Host): Loaded 'MassTransitGreenPipes.DynamicInternalxxx'.  The thread 0xbbbb has exited with code 0 (0x0). ERROR: Exception in Command Processing for EventSource Microsoft-Diagnostics-DiagnosticSource: Attempt by security transparent method 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSourceEventSource+FilterAndTransform.IsActivitySourceEntry(System.String, Int32, Int32)' to access security critical method 'System.MemoryExtensions.AsSpan(System.String, Int32, Int32)' failed.`

I'm using MassTransit 6.3.2; MassTransit.RabbitMQ 6.3.2; RabbitMQ.Client 5.2.0

Thank you!

I tried add `[assembly: SecurityRules(SecurityRuleSet.Level2, SkipVerificationInFullTrust = true)]` into AssemblyInfo.cs but no use

Comment: You're using an obsolete version of MassTransit. I'd suggest using the current version.